# single user, once with once without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, usermod

I have added a new user on my ubuntu machine with the following command:

```
sudo adduser test
```

and then granted him sudo with:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo test
```

So far everything seems pretty standard. The problem is that when I do:

```
su - test
sudo ls
```

everything works fine. But when I click "change user" and login to test user I get the following:

```
test@Rad:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for test: 
test is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
test@Rad:~$ su test
Password: 
test@Rad:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for test: 
config  Desktop  Documents  Downloads   Music  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos 
test@Rad:~$
```

I was trying to google what's wrong here, but I couldn't find antyhing similar to this case. To me it looks like the user is somehow duplicated? But how is it possible?

Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: What does `sudo -l` (for **test**) show?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks it actually helped! I feel kinda stupid now.

Comment: It all depends on how exactly you "changed user".

Answer (score 0):

From all appearances, the "change user" function had switched to an *existing* login session for that user -- one where they were not yet a part of the new group. Have that session log all the way out and back in, and they should be all set.